# How to efficiently compute rolling sum over multiple dates, grouping by id?

Tags: sql, rolling-sum

Given a table containing 1 line per day `dt` per `product_id` and the `turnover` generated this day, how to compute **efficiently** a column `turnover_7day` containing the turnover generated by this product over the last 7 days?

I found a simple query working as expected, but it's very slow and I'm trying to run the query for millions of products over the course of several years.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/82e836/15)
*(even if the Fiddle is Postgresql, IRL I'm trying to do this on Snowflake ; I doubt there are features  available in Snowflake that can completely change a potential answer to this post)*

## The dataset:

```
TABLE turnover_per_day:
| product_id | product_name |         dt | turnover |
|------------|--------------|------------|----------|
|          1 |          PS5 | 2021-10-22 |       85 |
|          1 |          PS5 | 2021-10-27 |      100 |
|          1 |          PS5 | 2021-11-01 |      110 |
|          1 |          PS5 | 2021-11-05 |      150 |
|          2 |         XBOX | 2021-11-02 |       10 |
|          2 |         XBOX | 2021-11-03 |       15 |
|          2 |         XBOX | 2021-11-04 |       13 |
|          2 |         XBOX | 2021-11-05 |       11 |
```

## Method 1: subquery in the SELECT statement (producing the expected result, very inefficient):

I'm using here a subquery on the source table in order to recompute the turnover. It seems really inefficient but at least it's easy to understand.

Query:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.product_id
    ,t1.product_name
    ,t1.turnover
    ,t1.dt
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(turnover) FROM turnover_per_day t2
        WHERE (t2.dt BETWEEN t1.dt - interval '6 day' AND t1.dt) and t1.product_id=t2.product_id
    ) as turnover_7day
FROM turnover_per_day as t1
order by product_id, t1.dt
```

Result (as intended):

```
| product_id | product_name | turnover |         dt | turnover_7day |
|------------|--------------|----------|------------|---------------|
|          1 |          PS5 |       85 | 2021-10-22 |            85 |
|          1 |          PS5 |      100 | 2021-10-27 |           185 |
|          1 |          PS5 |      110 | 2021-11-01 |           210 |
|          1 |          PS5 |      150 | 2021-11-05 |           260 |
|          2 |         XBOX |       10 | 2021-11-02 |            10 |
|          2 |         XBOX |       15 | 2021-11-03 |            25 |
|          2 |         XBOX |       13 | 2021-11-04 |            38 |
|          2 |         XBOX |       11 | 2021-11-05 |            49 |
```

## Method 2: trying to reproduce [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/131059) (but failing)

Here I'm trying to use window function in order to speed up the computation.
I tried to add `PARTITION BY product_id` on the answer linked above but it doesn't work out as it should.
My thinking is because of the `LEFT JOIN` values of the column `product_id` are `NULL` and when taking 6 previous ROW, it 'deletes' the NULL row hence summing over more than 6 days.

Query:

```sql
with days as ( -- generate a calendar without gap 
  SELECT date_trunc('day', d)::date as day
  FROM generate_series(CURRENT_DATE-15, CURRENT_DATE, '1 day'::interval) d
 )
select
    days.day
    ,t1.product_id
    ,t1.product_name
    ,t1.turnover
    ,t1.dt
    ,SUM(t1.turnover) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.product_id ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS turnover_7day

FROM days
LEFT JOIN turnover_per_day as t1
ON days.day = t1.dt
--where t1.product_id is not null
order by product_id, dt
```

Result (wrong):

```
|        day | product_id | product_name | turnover |         dt | turnover_7day |
|------------|------------|--------------|----------|------------|---------------|
| 2021-10-22 |          1 |          PS5 |       85 | 2021-10-22 |            85 |
| 2021-10-27 |          1 |          PS5 |      100 | 2021-10-27 |           185 |
| 2021-11-01 |          1 |          PS5 |      110 | 2021-11-01 |           295 |
| 2021-11-05 |          1 |          PS5 |      150 | 2021-11-05 |           445 |
| 2021-11-02 |          2 |         XBOX |       10 | 2021-11-02 |            10 |
| 2021-11-03 |          2 |         XBOX |       15 | 2021-11-03 |            25 |
| 2021-11-04 |          2 |         XBOX |       13 | 2021-11-04 |            38 |
| 2021-11-05 |          2 |         XBOX |       11 | 2021-11-05 |            49 |
| 2021-10-31 |     (null) |       (null) |   (null) |     (null) |        (null) |
| 2021-10-29 |     (null) |       (null) |   (null) |     (null) |        (null) |
| 2021-10-23 |     (null) |       (null) |   (null) |     (null) |        (null) |
| 2021-10-24 |     (null) |       (null) |   (null) |     (null) |        (null) |
| 2021-10-25 |     (null) |       (null) |   (null) |     (null) |        (null) |
| 2021-10-26 |     (null) |       (null) |   (null) |     (null) |        (null) |
| 2021-10-28 |     (null) |       (null) |   (null) |     (null) |        (null) |
| 2021-10-21 |     (null) |       (null) |   (null) |     (null) |        (null) |
| 2021-10-30 |     (null) |       (null) |   (null) |     (null) |        (null) |
```

My questions are:

1. How to modify the Method 2 in order to make it work?
2. Are there any other less data/computation-intensive way to calculate this rolling sum (group by product_id)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ROWS PRECEDING, which is counted in number of rows, you need to use RANGE PRECEDING, which is counted in units of the ORDER BY column.

```
select
    t1.product_id
    ,t1.product_name
    ,t1.turnover
    ,t1.dt
    ,SUM(t1.turnover) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.product_id ORDER BY dt RANGE BETWEEN '6 days' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS turnover_7day
FROM turnover_per_day as t1
order by product_id, dt;
```

The ROW PRECEDING method could be made to work if you created the dense series of days *for each product*, which you are not doing in your code.  But I doubt it would perform well.

Comment: Neither Snowflake nor PostgreSQL have RANGE BETWEEN implemented for rolling window functions https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#window-frame-usage-notes

Comment: I tested it in PostgreSQL before posting and it works there.  Implemented in v11, it looks like.  I wouldn't know about snowflake.  Your first attempt also gives reasonable performance with the right index (again, in PostgreSQL--I still wouldn't know about snowflake)